# Install an MSI into Azure Service Fabric node

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

How can I install a MSI into service fabric remotely or after a deployment? I have an install I need on each node in the cluster. Using Remote Desktop and running the MSI is not an option. I need something that scales. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this using the SetupEntryPoint and ExeHost in the ServiceManifest.xml file. See the documentation here [Documentation to SetupEntryPoint](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-application-model/#describe-a-service)

Comment: There are a few drawbacks to this approach: 1) SetupEntryPoint runs every time your service host EntryPoint is started on a node. Be prepared for it to run multiple times on the same node over the life of your service. 2) There's no clean-up option. Every node your service is activated on will end up with this installed on it. 3) It always runs to completion before your service is activated, potentially slowing down activation of the service host.

Comment: It sounds like what you are really after is down at the VM Scale Set level - a way to get something installed on the VMs before running your Service Fabric applications. Check out VM Custom Script extensions for that: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-extensions-customscript/

Comment: Good point Vaclav. I am testing with custom script extensions now on my VM Scaleset

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at Desired State Configuration (DSC) there is an extension which you can use within your ARM template, it is a big topic so here is a couple of links that might help get you started.

[vmss with dsc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machine-scale-sets-dsc/)

[installing msi with dsc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/packageresource)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do I need to create a new Automation resource for this or use the automation tab on service fabric? I am unclear on how to add resources to my current Service Fabric cluster.

Comment: It's not really related to Service Fabric. You own the VMs in your Service Fabric cluster, and what you're trying to do is install an MSI on the VMs. So as jimpaine said, you can do that by submitting an updated ARM template. More info here on ARM here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-template-deploy/

Comment: Thanks I talked with another MS Azure engineer and they pointed me to SetupEntryPoint which worked to get the MSI installed. I have some learning to do on ARM templates.